# Unknown host exception, Unable to resolve host. No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am developing a client server application on Android, and I encountered the error from the title. What I am trying to do is, using Volley, to connect to my C# server which is deployed through IIS on my desktop.

This is the code where I encounter the error (url is redacted for privacy reasons).

```
 private void validate(final String userName,final String userPassword)
 {
    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    String url = "http://hostname//urlExample/urlExample/urlExample/urlExample";
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            if (response.compareTo("true") == 0)
            {
                pDialog.hide();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                pDialog.hide();
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Can't login");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Invalid username or password");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error occurred ", error);
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", userName);
            params.put("password", userPassword);

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
}
```

In the URL field where it's written "hostname" I have my Windows Desktop Host Name which was taken from ipconfig /all. The URL works on my PC if I try to access it, but it doesn't work on my phone, not even in the browser.

I already added android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE in my manifest file. I don't have VPNs activated, I don't use custom DNS or have my phone rooted, I checked that internet works, that both the phone and PC are connected to the same router, that both use the same DNS. I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Use your desktop's ip address instead. or set up a dns server to resolve hostnames for different devices/machines on your network.

Comment: you can try to enable logs for Volley like described [here](https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/5980715) and check if your url is correct. Possibly with Postman or Curl

Comment: I specified I already checked the URL if it works on PC, and it does. The same URL I use on the PC doesn't work on the phone, not even in the browser. I also saw the error from the title in the logs.